# User defined type guard function and type narrowing to more specific type

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Let's say I have the following user defined type guard function that checks if a value is a number above `1000`:

```
function isBigNumber(something: unknown): something is number {
    return typeof something === "number" && something > 1000;
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
const strOrNum: string | number = "asdf";

if (isBigNumber(someVar)) {
    console.log(someVar * 10); // works because of type-guard
} else {
    // here type of strOrNum is "string" and no longer "string | number"
}
```

My problem is with the type of `strOrNum` in the Else block.

It looks like that the type guard checks for the type and TS also uses the type guard to narrow down the type for the Else block which in this case is not what I want. Are type guards only meant to check the type and no additional information of values passed to them?

Is there a solution to this without changing the return type of `isBigNumber` to `boolean` and having to check the type of `strOrNum` again for the If statement?

Comment: Why don't you separate the number type predicate from the `> 1000` condition?

Comment: @GuerricP could be a solution. Let's say this check happens a lot. Then it would make sense to use such a function.

Comment: just to confirm, your actual case is for large numbers without a specific finite range? If the expected values is small enough to use a union that'd work but otherwise I think you are in for an annoying amount of refactoring

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen this is a simpler example of the actual use case I have in a project. It looks like that checking for a subset of a type and then using the broader type as the type guard's return type is not a good idea.

Comment: it is specifically that `number` is atomic in typescript, it might be possible there will be number ranges in the future that would allow this use-case but right now that isn't a thing. If you had something like `something is 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1004....` and that served your usage it might work but if non integers are needed or the range is not finite then there isn't much you can do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no `>1000` type. If you were dealing in a finite, known, set of numbers, you could do something like `something is 1001 | 1002 | 1003 | 1004 | 1005`, and Typescript would keep track of that (and would understand that in a `false` case `something` could still be (some other) `number`), but you’re not.

The solution here is “type branding,” which is effectively a way to “fake” nominal typing in Typescript’s structural type system. There are a number of approaches, and several libraries you could install, but for this I’m just going to use my own, which I just call `As`. I’ve included `As` at the bottom of this answer, along with some explanations, but it’s also fine to just use it as a black box.

The way `As` works is that you can say something is, say, `As<"big-number">`, and Typescript will respect that and keep track of this thing that is a big number. It exists purely in the type system, and completely disappears from the compiled Javascript. With it, you can write functions that only accept big numbers, you can write typeguards that confirm big numbers, and so on.

One of the really crucial things about these brands is that if you have a typeguard that says `something is X & As<"whatever">`, Typescript will understand that `something` might still be `X`, because it might be the `As<"whatever">` portion that `something` is missing. This gets around your issue with your typeguard.

So, for your example:

```
type BigNumber = number & As<"big-number">;

function isBigNumber(something: unknown): something is BigNumber {
    return typeof something === "number" && something > 1000;
}

function onBigNumber(value: BigNumber): void {
  console.log(value - 1000); // works because BigNumber extends number
}

declare const strOrNum: string | number;

if (isBigNumber(strOrNum)) {
  console.log(strOrNum * 10); // works because of type-guard
  onBigNumber(strOrNum); // works because of type-guard
} else {
  // here type of strOrNum is "string | number"
  if (typeof strOrNum === "number") {
    console.log(strOrNum * 100); // works because of type-guard
    onBigNumber(strOrNum); // ERROR, because strOrNum is number but not As<"big-number">
  }
}
```

---

#### Definition of `As`

```
declare abstract class As<Tag extends keyof never> {
  private static readonly $as$: unique symbol;
  private [As.$as$]: Record<Tag, true>;
}
```

Some key notes if you want to understand this instead of just treating it as a black box:

- `declare` means TS won’t generate code for this class—it tells TS that the runtime JS for this class already exists, we’re just informing TS of its existence. That’s a lie, in this case—this class doesn’t exist at all.
- `abstract` prevents us from attempting `new As`, which would cause a runtime error because of the “lie” discussed above. It does not prevent us from trying `class X extends As`, that will compile, and would also cause a runtime error. Don’t do that. (You could `declare class X extends As` if you wanted to extend the lie, though.)
- `Tag extends keyof never` makes `As` generic, so we can use it with many different brands. `keyof never` is the weird best practice for determining the type union corresponding to legal JS object keys (`string | number | symbol`).
- `private [As.$as$]` tells Typescript that objects of this class have a private member, that is, that its structure is different and specific. That means that Typescript’s structural typing system will treat this as a different type. It’s `private`, so no one can access it (which is good because this is another lie), and using `As.$as$`, which is defined as a `unique symbol`, guarantees we won’t have any name conflicts with whatever we apply this brand to.
- `Record<Tag, true>` as the type of the private member “stores” whatever `Tag` is passed into the class’s generic parameters. Making it a `Record` allows multiple brands to co-exist on the same object.

Comment: This is interesting. Why do you need the `Record`? Isn't every different type parameter you pass to `As` going to create a different class type?

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla Because Typescript is a structural typing system, any class is type-equivalent to any other object with the same members. So we have to tell TS it actually has some member based on `Tag` to get it to recognize that one `As` is not equivalent to some other `As` (or to an empty object, in the case of `As` defined without any members at all).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I always forget about the structural typing of TS. I'll try this and see how it works.

Comment: I've tried this now and it works great. Just one note: I put the abstract class in a `declare global` block so that it is available everywhere in the code base.